# Android: IF statement with radio buttons not working

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a quiz app, so there are 5 radio buttons with possible answers, and only 1 is correct. Then there's a submit button, which has an onClick="clickMethod" to process the submission.

My clickMethod looks like this:

```
public void clickMethod(View v){
                RadioGroup group1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
                int selected = group1.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                RadioButton button1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(selected);
                if (button1.getText()=="Right Answer")
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Correct!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Incorrect.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

However I can't get the IF statement to work no matter what. If I try to make the toast with 
 "button1.getText()" as parameter it does print the "Right Answer" string, but for some reason inside the IF statement it's not working, and the ELSE is always executed even when I check the right answer.

Does anyone know what might be happening or a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `equals` String method for String comparison:

```
public void clickMethod(View v){
    RadioGroup group1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
    int selected = group1.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    RadioButton button1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(selected);
    if ("Right Answer".equals(button1.getText())) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Correct!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Incorrect.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You're not comparing strings correctly.

> The == operator is used when we have to compare the String object
>   references. If two String variables point to the same object in
>   memory, the comparison returns true. Otherwise, the comparison returns
>   false. Note that the ‘==’ operator does not compare the content of the
>   text present in the String objects. It only compares the references
>   the 2 Strings are pointing to.

Read here: http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-string-comparison

Comment: Thanks. I'll check that website as well.

Answer (score 1):

In Java you can't compare Strings with `==` you have to use `equals()`:

```
if (button1.getText().equals("Right Answer"))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare objects in Java you have to use equals() method and not the == operator
..

```
if (button1.getText().toString().equals("Right Answer")) {
 Toast.makeText(this,"Correct!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else {
 Toast.makeText(this,"Incorrect.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```